# Trying to animate a SolidColorBrush static resource

Tags: wpf, animation, resourcedictionary, brush, staticresource

#### What I'd like

I want to reuse some styles across multiple `UserControl` types.

I would like the background of some `Border` controls to flash, and I'd like them all to use the same style, static resource and animation, so that they all flash in sync.

---

#### How I'm trying to do it

To that end, I have defined some common colours in a resource dictionary, like so:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="StatusErrorBackground" Color="#440000" />
```

...and I have also defined a StoryBoard in this dictionary, like so:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="BackgroundAnimation">
    <ColorAnimation
        Storyboard.Target="{StaticResource StatusErrorBackground}"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
        From="#440000"
        To="#ff0000"
        Duration="0:0:1"
        RepeatBehavior="Forever"
        AutoReverse="True"/>
</Storyboard>
```

I've then added the following to a top-level `UserControl`:

```
<FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="CommonResources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</FrameworkElement.Resources>

<FrameworkElement.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource BackgroundAnimation}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</FrameworkElement.Triggers>
```

...and then in various other `UserControl`s that are children of that, I re-import the `ResourceDictionary` as above and use the `{StaticResource StatusErrorBackground}` for a `Background`.

The elements in question are coloured red (as in the `SolidColorBrush` declaration), *but they're not flashing*.

---

#### Fuzzy understanding thus far

Maybe doing this doesn't raise the appropriate PropertyChanged notifications on the elements in question, so they're not redrawn? Or something like that. The `Color` property on `SolidColorBrush` isn't a dependency property, but `SolidColorBrush` implements `IAnimatable`, so there's obviously magic happening behind the scenes here I don't understand.

Or is it that because I'm importing the same resource dictionary in two different places (once in my top-level `UserControl` plus once in my child) that I end up with two independent `StaticResource` references? If you import the same `ResourceDictionary` file in two different controls, does it create independent resources for each? In which case I might be able to fix this by pulling it in at an app level, I guess...

Can anyone tell me what I doing wrong and how I might go about fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really say why, but it works if you add a dummy object, e.g. a Rectangle that uses the SolidColorBrush for its `Fill` property, and then animate that `Fill`. Now the SolidColorBrush's Color gets animated.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="StatusErrorBackground" Color="#440000" />
<Rectangle x:Key="StatusErrorBackgroundRectangle" Fill="{StaticResource StatusErrorBackground}"/>

<Storyboard x:Key="BackgroundAnimation">
    <ColorAnimation 
        Storyboard.Target="{DynamicResource StatusErrorBackgroundRectangle}" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
        ... />
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Yours works because you are animating the Rectangle as the Storyboard.Target.  He has multiple targets and wants to animate them.

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks. To answer some of my own question, I definitely end up with two independent StaticResource references when I do this from different UserControls (which makes sense I guess), so I first need to pull this out into a top-level resource anyway. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: This works for me to. I don't know why. It's annoying that animating the Brush directly does not seem to work

Comment: Be warned: This will not work if you set the Color of the Brush using a XAML "type converter" e.g. <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StatusErrorBackground" >Yellow</SolidColorBrush>

Answer (score 9):

I know I'm late here, but I found this question when I was attempting to animate to and from colours that are held in solid brushes. The brushes are part of a resource dictionary that other people are using, and I don't want to change. I just made this, very quickly to try out and it appeared to work.

```
public class SolidColorAnimation : ColorAnimation
{
    public SolidColorBrush ToBrush
    {
        get { return To == null ? null : new SolidColorBrush(To.Value); }
        set { To = value?.Color; }
    }
}
```

and use it in the xaml like this:

```
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard >
                        <ui:SolidColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" ToBrush="{StaticResource NavButtonRolloverBrush}" Duration="0:0:0.75"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard >
                        <ui:SolidColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" ToBrush="{StaticResource NavButtonBrush}" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

`<Color x:Key="name" A="0" R="255" G="255" B="255"/>`

insteade of

`<SolidColorBrush x:Key="name" Color="#0fff"/>`

that works for me