# How to animate SolidColorBrush resource?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, coloranimation

I'm trying to animate SolidColorBrush, which is the resource of my custom control. This brush is used as the fill for five rectangles.

While on **design time**, all works as expected, but at **run time** the app closes immediately with System.InvalidOperationException, pointing that the brush's name couldn't be found.

I started a sample project, having:

- 1 brush, which I would like to animate

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Name="rectBrush" x:Key="rectangleBrush" Color="#b266b2" />
```

- 5 rectangles, which are filled using that brush.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Rectangle
            Fill="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}" />
        <Rectangle
            Fill="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}" />
        <Rectangle
            Fill="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}" />
        <Rectangle
            Fill="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}" />
        <Rectangle
            Fill="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I'm using Blend for Visual Studio to see if the storyboard is correct and working.

On launch I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: ''rectBrush' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'AnimationExample.MainWindow'

Complete XAML markup:

```
<Window x:Class="AnimationExample.MainWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="rectBrush" x:Key="rectangleBrush" Color="#b266b2" />
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="6" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="6" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
            <Setter Property="RadiusX" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="3" />
        </Style>
        <Storyboard 
            x:Key="NowPlayingAnimation"
            RepeatBehavior="Forever"
            AutoReverse="True">
            <ColorAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="rectBrush"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                From="#b266b2"
                To="#6666ff"
                Duration="0:0:1" />
            <ColorAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="rectBrush"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                From="#6666ff"
                To="#66b266"
                Duration="0:0:1"
                BeginTime="0:0:1"/>
            <ColorAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="rectBrush"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                From="#66b266"
                To="#ffff66"
                Duration="0:0:1"
                BeginTime="0:0:2"/>
            <ColorAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="rectBrush"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                From="#ffff66"
                To="#ffc966"
                Duration="0:0:1"
                BeginTime="0:0:3" />
            <ColorAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="rectBrush"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                From="#ffc966"
                To="#ff4c4c"
                Duration="0:0:1"
                BeginTime="0:0:4" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource NowPlayingAnimation}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}" />
            <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}" />
            <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}" />
            <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}" />
            <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have two questions:

1. Why on design time all works fine and I'm able to see what I actually would like to get?
2. Is there a way to achieve this?

   - completely in XAML;
   - without animating each rectangle's fill individually?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11906988/1136211

Comment: @Clemens, yeah, I saw. he was using rectangle as a dummy object to animate only one element. I'm trying to animate multiple rectangles using one SolidColorBrush.

Comment: Animating `Fill.Color` of the dummy Rectangle will actually animate the SolidColorBrush resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two options:

1. Put the animation in the Style, and directly animate `Background.Color`.
2. Put the brush someplace where it, or its parent, is in the visual tree where a name can be resolved.

Version 2:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="rectBrush" x:Key="rectangleBrush" Color="#b266b2" />
    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="6" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="6" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
        <Setter Property="RadiusX" Value="3" />
        <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="3" />
    </Style>
    <Storyboard 
        x:Key="NowPlayingAnimation"
        RepeatBehavior="Forever"
        AutoReverse="True">
        <ColorAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="BrushCarrier"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag.Color"
            From="#b266b2"
            To="#6666ff"
            Duration="0:0:1" />
        <ColorAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="BrushCarrier"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag.Color"
            From="#6666ff"
            To="#66b266"
            Duration="0:0:1"
            BeginTime="0:0:1"/>
        <ColorAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="BrushCarrier"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag.Color"
            From="#66b266"
            To="#ffff66"
            Duration="0:0:1"
            BeginTime="0:0:2"/>
        <ColorAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="BrushCarrier"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag.Color"
            From="#ffff66"
            To="#ffc966"
            Duration="0:0:1"
            BeginTime="0:0:3" />
        <ColorAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="BrushCarrier"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag.Color"
            From="#ffc966"
            To="#ff4c4c"
            Duration="0:0:1"
            BeginTime="0:0:4" />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource NowPlayingAnimation}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <FrameworkElement
        x:Name="BrushCarrier"
        Tag="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}"
        />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}" />
        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}" />
        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}" />
        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}" />
        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Version 1. Here, the storyboard isn't defined as a resource, and you don't start it when the window is loaded. Each Rectangle takes care of its own animation.

```
<Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="ColorShiftRectangle">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="6" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="6" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
    <Setter Property="RadiusX" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#b266b2" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard 
                    RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                    AutoReverse="True">
                    <ColorAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
                        From="#b266b2"
                        To="#6666ff"
                        Duration="0:0:1" />
                    <ColorAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
                        From="#6666ff"
                        To="#66b266"
                        Duration="0:0:1"
                        BeginTime="0:0:1"/>
                    <ColorAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
                        From="#66b266"
                        To="#ffff66"
                        Duration="0:0:1"
                        BeginTime="0:0:2"/>
                    <ColorAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
                        From="#ffff66"
                        To="#ffc966"
                        Duration="0:0:1"
                        BeginTime="0:0:3" />
                    <ColorAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
                        From="#ffc966"
                        To="#ff4c4c"
                        Duration="0:0:1"
                        BeginTime="0:0:4" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
    <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource ColorShiftRectangle}" />
```

Comment: `BrushCarrier` doesn't actually need to be a named element in the visual tree. It could as well be a resource and referenced by `Storyboard.Target`

Comment: @Clemens How would I do that? This doesn't animate the brush color: `Storyboard.Target="{StaticResource rectangleBrush}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"`

Comment: @EdPlunkett, actually I have found the second (as you call it: version 1) solution a minute ago! :DThat isn't nice, because I cannot actually see this animation in designer and it's harder to modify, but it works!

Comment: @vershart I'm surprised it doesn't work in the designer. However, my and Clemens' workarounds for your original design both aren't animating in the VS XAML designer for me either.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, that's a good solution, it just doesn't show in Blend timeline editor, because it starts only when the rectangle is initialized and animation is part of this element. That's fine. I'll accept it. But one more question: why on Earth my first attempt was working in Blend and Visual Studio editor?

Comment: @vershart The XAML designer does a few things differently than they're done at runtime. That would appear to be one of them.